# Unexpected billing on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, aws-billing

I am doing some checkings in billing console and there I found a c5.xlarge instance that I can't find on EC2 console. I am searching for these instances on the correct Region that is sa-east-1 in my case and the heading of the bill is **Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud running Linux/UNIX**.
How can I check all EC2 related instances in a region? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the region on your bill detail

- Services > Billing
- Bills > Details > Expand All

You should also check any Volumes, Elastic ips are using in your account.

Another way is go to the ec2 directly.

Change region one by one to check if any resources are in used.